# Backing up my GPO's

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

If I wanted to backup everything related to all my GPO's - permissions, links for the domain (how they are linked to my OU's etc), and all the GPO's themselves, how would I go about doing that.

I see a lot of references to Powershell and using Backup All in Group Policy Management, but does that back up the links and permissions too?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create a System State Backup from one of your domain controllers as all these things are integrated in AD. You can do this with `ntbackup` (windows 2000/2003) or `Windows Server Backup` (windows 2008+).

If you want to be able to restore single elements though you'd most probably have to use 3rd party software which is able to granularly restore objects into AD.